# A public action method 'ReusableIndex' was not found on controller after 9.3 Upgrade

Tags: sxa, upgrade

Just upgraded Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1 to Sitecore 9.3 and SXA 9.3.

After the upgrade a few components are throwing the following exception:

```
Error Rendering Controller: Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageContent.Controllers.RichTextController,Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageContent. Action: ReusableIndex: A public action method 'ReusableIndex' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageContent.Controllers.RichTextController'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

I have checked that all the binaries are the correct 9.3 version and that all the configuration is correct.

The problem doesn't happen on all pages, only some of them.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is due to a breaking change somewhere between SXA 1.8.1 and SXA 9.3.

In 1.8.1 the `RichTextController` looks like this:

```
public class RichTextController : VariantsController
{
    public ActionResult ReusableIndex()
    {
        return (ActionResult) this.PartialView("RichText", this.GetModel());
    }
}
```

In 9.3 that `ReuseableIndex` method has been removed. It looks like this:

```
public class RichTextController : VariantsController
{
}
```

So if you have cloned any components from the `RichTextComponent (Reusable)`, then you may have this problem after an upgrade. Change your rendering to use the `Index` action instead of the `ReusableIndex` action and it will work again.